# Element over youtube video clicks through on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

This is a really problematic issue, which seems to have no solutions, so I hope you can help with it.

The issue is when adding an element over youtube video iframe, it shouldn't let to click the video and it doesn't on desktop version. But on mobile it clicks through the element if the video appears near to the side of the main window and the target is at the side too.

Try the jsfiddle in device mode and try to click the video at the side of the main window (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzxbD.png):

https://jsfiddle.net/vjtfopdw/

Code to test:

```html
<iframe width="560" height="349" class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tvIXmaJMD8M?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;playsinline=1" frameborder="0" wmode="opaque" allowfullscreen="" ></iframe>

<div style="
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999999;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);">
</div>
```

I've tried setting higher zindex, moving the element more to each side, adding and removing wmode=transparent & opaque, nothing helps.

Comment: if you dont want click , just add css `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: On my script the box over the video is going only at the bottom and side, so I want to be able to click the video where it's needed, but prevent it from clicking on the sides. @Durga